# image management in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

in my application i am uploading the image into database. before it is store in the database, i want to do image management like decreasing size and decreasing height and width of the image. can u help me. is there any source code or any reference please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What codebehind language are you using?

I find 4guysfromrolla to be a good ASP.NET reference, try this article for starters:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111640/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012203-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about something like creating a thumbnail image. the Image() class will let you scale an existing image up or down.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

You want to be looking at the `System.Drawing` name space for manipulating images with ASP.NET. You can load any supported image file type (i.e. jpg, gif, png, etc) using `Image.FromFile()`, `Image.FromStream()`, etc. From there you use the Drawing Graphics context to manipulate the image. To give you a flavour here is my resize image function:

```
// Creates a re-sized image from the SourceFile provided that retails the same aspect ratio of the SourceImage. 
// -    If either the width or height dimensions is not provided then the resized image will use the 
//      proportion of the provided dimension to calculate the missing one.
// -    If both the width and height are provided then the resized image will have the dimensions provided 
//      with the sides of the excess portions clipped from the center of the image.
public static Image ResizeImage(Image sourceImage, int? newWidth, int? newHeight)
{
    bool doNotScale = newWidth == null || newHeight == null; ;

    if (newWidth == null)
    {
        newWidth = (int)(sourceImage.Width * ((float)newHeight / sourceImage.Height));
    }
    else if (newHeight == null)
    {
        newHeight = (int)(sourceImage.Height * ((float)newWidth) / sourceImage.Width);
    }

    var targetImage = new Bitmap(newWidth.Value, newHeight.Value);

    Rectangle srcRect;
    var desRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth.Value, newHeight.Value);

    if (doNotScale)
    {
        srcRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, sourceImage.Width, sourceImage.Height);
    }
    else
    {
        if (sourceImage.Height > sourceImage.Width)
        {
            // clip the height
            int delta = sourceImage.Height - sourceImage.Width;
            srcRect = new Rectangle(0, delta / 2, sourceImage.Width, sourceImage.Width);
        }
        else
        {
            // clip the width
            int delta = sourceImage.Width - sourceImage.Height;
            srcRect = new Rectangle(delta / 2, 0, sourceImage.Height, sourceImage.Height);
        }
    }

    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(targetImage))
    {
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        g.DrawImage(sourceImage, desRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }

    return targetImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the image class or a 3rd party DLL such as ASPJPEG. A few ASPJPEG samples can be found [here](http://www.aspjpeg.com/manual_02.html). I do a lot of image processing and my host [reliablesite](http://www.reliablesite.net/v3/shared.asp) supports this dll on their servers.